# What feats grant both weapon proficiency and bonus damage, without a race requirement?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats

Turathi Weapon Training (Tiefling), Githzerai Blade Master (Githzerai), and Xen'drik Weapon Training (Drow), and a couple others I think I'm forgetting—Proficiency *and* (a lot of) bonus damage with weapons, some of them Superior? Awesome.

They all seem to have a race requirement though. Are there any that don't?

Comment: related question, are you trying to optimize a character build? If so you can post character build optimization questions here as well.

Answer (score 4):

**Reaper's Blade** (Dragon 427) grants proficiency with and +2/+3/+4 damage bonus to the sickle and the scythe. It requires worshipping Nerull.

**Vigilant Associate** (Dragon 376) grants proficiency with and +1 damage bonus to the short sword. (It also gives you CA against an enemy you intimidate.) It requires the Tarmalune regional background.

**Moonbow Dedicate** (Dragon 386) grants proficiency with and +1/+2/+3 damage bonus to the shortbow. (It also lets you use the shortbow as an implement for divine and arcane powers.) It requires worshipping Sehanine.

Note that Moonbow Dedicate specifically grants the damage bonus to weapon and implement damage rolls with the shortbow, while the other feats don't specify. In practice, there's not much difference, though.

There are no other feats I could find which give both proficiency and a damage bonus without having a racial requirement. (Unless there's such a feat which isn't listed in the DDI, which is possible but unlikely.)

Comment: `Moonbow Dedicate` from *Dragon Magazine 386* also grant proficiency and damage bonus with shortbow, plus the ability to use it as an implement.